# Возможно ли выполнение Win формы без отображения

Tags: c#, winforms

Приступил к расширению функционала и главная форма стала вторичной.

В ней есть таймер который запускает последовательность методов при бездействии человека.

Возможно ли запустить форму без отображения, чтобы таймер сам запустил работу, а при надобности, по нажатию кнопки человеком, форма отобразилась без перезапуска?

Comment: Форма - это обычный класс. Что вы в ней напишете, то и запустите.

Comment: Суть вопроса в том, возможно ли "отрисовать" форму после, по надобности

Comment: а не назрел ли вопрос рефакторинга кода? Может вам стоит перенести функционал, выполняемый не только в одной форме, как отдельный, и соответственно использовать когда это нужно?

Comment: я же говорю, это обычный класс, вы можете создать форму в одно время, а отрисовать тогда, когда захочется - вы же вызываете методы классов тогда, когда вам хочется? Вот тут то же самое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете вызвать метод Hide. Единственно его надо вызывать когда форма показывается (конструктор для этого не подходит). Вот так:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    VisibleChanged += Form1_VisibleChanged;
}

private void Form1_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Hide();
}
```

Теперь форма будет не видна. Но лучше так не делать, т.к. ресурсы на визуальные компоненты все равно будут выделены. Если в форме именно визуальная часть вам не нужна, то пересоберите нужный вам функционал в отдельный класс и используйте его.

Comment: а возможно ли отключить Hide(); из другой формы без перезапуска данной формы ?

Comment: Можно. Для этого у вас должна быть переменная в которой есть ссылка на нужную форму. И вызываете Hide через эту переменную.

Comment: Вы проверяли этот код? Есть ощущение, что форма никогда не покажется, так как при попытке отобразить форму будет вызываться ваш обработчик, что форму скрывает. А при попытке скрыть форму этот обработчик второй раз её скроет? А если 2 раза подряд скрыть форму, вызовится обработчик? (Если да, то у вас бесконечный цикл)

Comment: @tym32167 Бесконечного цикла цикла вроде нет (Hide не вызывает VisibleChanged, если форма была уже скрыта), но да, этот код дает вечно скрытую форму

Comment: Если форма не должна быть все время скрыта, то да, решение об этом лучше принимать не в методе изменения визуального состояния. Судя по вашему вопросу про вторую форму, вам даже это событие не нужно. Во второй форме и принимайте решение, когда показывать форму, а когда скрывать. И,да, вечного цикла не будет.

Comment: `Если форма не должна быть все время скрыта` не очень ясен смысл формы, что все время скрыта

Comment: Автор в проекте заменил главную форму на другую. И "старая" главная нужна ему ради таймеров которые на ней крутятся, по крайней мере я так понял из описания.